# java String.replaceAll char between two numbers

Tags: java, replace, insert, char, between

I would like to replace all char '-' that between two  numbers, or that between number and '.' by char '&'.For example

String input=  "2.1(-7-11.3)-12.1*-2.3-.11"
String output= "2.1(-7&11.3)-12.1*-2.3&.11"

I have something like this, but I try to do it easier.

```
public void preperString(String input) {

    input=input.replaceAll(" ","");
    input=input.replaceAll(",",".");                
    input=input.replaceAll("-","&");             
    input=input.replaceAll("\\(&","\\(-");         
    input=input.replaceAll("\\[&","\\[-");         
    input=input.replaceAll("\\+&","\\+-");
    input=input.replaceAll("\\*&","\\*-");
    input=input.replaceAll("/&","/-");
    input=input.replaceAll("\\^&","\\^-");
    input=input.replaceAll("&&","&-");
    input=input.replaceFirst("^&","-");

    for (String s :input.split("[^.\\-\\d]")) {
        if (!s.equals(""))
        numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
    }
```

Comment: Do it in one call: `replaceAll("(?!\\.-\\.)([0-9.])-([0-9.])", "$1&$2")`. See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wNzXQ3/1) for demo.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it in one shot using groups of regex to solve your problem, you can use this :

```
String input = "2.1(-7-11.3)-12.1*-2.3-.11";
input = input.replaceAll("([\\d.])-([\\d.])", "$1&$2");
```

**Output**

```
2.1(-7&11.3)-12.1*-2.3&.11
```

---

```
  ([\\d.])-([\\d.])
//        ^------------replace the hyphen(-) that it between
// ^__________^--------two number(\d)
//   ^_^______^_^------or between number(\d) and dot(.)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/idPihS/1)

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess.  You don't really have a use for `&` here; you're just trying to replace certain minus signs with `&` so that they won't interfere with the `split` that you're trying to use to find all the numbers (so that the `split` doesn't return `"-7-11"` as one of the array elements, in your original example).  Is that correct?

If my guess is right, then the correct answer is: don't use `split`.  It is the wrong tool for the job.  The purpose of `split` is to split up a string by looking for delimiter patterns (such as a sequence of whitespace or a comma); but where the format of the elements between the delimiters doesn't much matter.  In your case, though, you are looking for elements of a particular numeric format (it might start with `-`, and otherwise will have at least one digit and at most one period; I don't know what your exact requirements are).  In this case, instead of `split`, the right way to do this is to create a regular expression for the pattern you want your numbers to have, and then use `m.find` in a loop (where `m` is a `Matcher`) to get all your numbers.

If you need to treat some `-` characters differently (e.g. in `-7-11`, where you want the second `-` to be an operator and not part of -11), then you can make special checks for that in your loop, and skip over the `-` signs that you know you want to treat as operators.

It's simpler, readers will understand what you're trying to do, and it's less error-prone because all you have to do is make sure your pattern for expressing numbers accurately reflects what you're looking for.

It's common for newer Java programmers to think regexes and `split` are magic tools that can solve everything.  But often the result ends up being too complex (code uses overly complicated regexes, or relies on trickery like having to replace characters with `&` temporarily).  I cannot look at your original code and convince myself that it works right.  It's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match digit or dot:

```
input.replaceAll("(?<=[\\d\\.])-(?=[\\d\\.])","&")
```

Have a look on this [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/A4Aj6u/1).